# Spring security http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true) is not coming in response headers?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, http-headers

Spring security `http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true)` is not coming in response headers?

version : `Spring-seucrity-config-4.2.3.RELEASE`

I am on HTTPS , tried with HTTP also.

After enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) using spring security its not visible in the response headers of the request in the browser.

Is this wrong configuration or not supported.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().cacheControl().and()
        .frameOptions().and()
        .contentTypeOptions().and()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).and()
        .xssProtection().and()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN)
        .and().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'"));
    }
```

Comment: Please add your configuration not just the line you tried to use to configure things.

Comment: added the configuration